# Do you need to add "Unrestricted Web Access" if you open links in Safari?

Tags: ios, app-store

My app uses this line of code to open my Facebook page in Safari:

```
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) {
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "myFacebookPageLink"))
}
```

Do I need to set "Unrestricted Web Access" to YES when submitting to the App Store?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the Safari browser, you do not need to add the "Unrestricted Web Access", as the docs call it:

> Unrestricted web access, such as with an embedded browser
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/FirstSteps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH19-SW34

Basically if people can browse the web with your app freely, you need to check it.